# Magento Configurations are not changing after saving

Tags: php, magento

after updating to magento 1.8.1 it stopped saving the changes of the theme options in the system configuration… i made a backup and created 1 to 1 copy on my local machine… and by editing the theme options.. and saving!! everything is ok !!!

i can’t understand y the problem is only on the server… i mean these r the same files.. the same database… and everything is ok with the permissions… and the php version is by both 5.4… so i have no idea why it should function on my local server and not on the web server !!!

after saving… i still get the message “The configuration has been saved.” the problem is it's not being saved...
it's only about the theme options.. other Configurations can be saved normally...

so i can't understand y.. and i don't know where to look !!!

it’s driving me almost crazy

i made a screen capture to give a hint how it looks like:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBfIWXxGB64&feature=youtu.be

Comment: delete cache folder from the var

Comment: no change.. still the **same**

Answer (score 12):

Nothing happens when you try to save the payment methods page. The problem is caused by the Chrome browser's auto-fill feature. Chrome will auto-fill the PayPal username/email. Click on the PayPal Payment Solutions tab, then click Configure near Express Checkout and remove the auto-filled username/password.

Now you can save the page.

Alternatively, try FireFox, Safari or Internet Explorer.

Taken from [this page](http://help.appmerce.com/support/articles/1000012541-cannot-save-the-payment-methods-admin)

Comment: How the hell did you find this? Good job!

Answer (score 4):

This is 100% cache issue.
Clearing cache folder from **magento_root/var** does not clear all cache created by magento.
You need to clear cache from magento admin:

**flush magento cache**

and

**flush cache storage**

If that wont help, try to clear /tmp directory on server.

Also: if it's a theme related configuration issue, maybe after upgrade some file permissions have been changed.

Comment: sorry but it didn't work :(
i used magento cleanup tool to reset all permissions and clear the cache...
then i did what told.. 

flush magento cache
flush cache storage
clear /tmp directory on server

still have the same problem...

Comment: Does the data stay the same in all input fields in system configuration, or does the theme on frontend not change at all?

Comment: I would take a look into database table core_config_data and check if some records are not duplicated - happens sometimes

Comment: i deleted all records of the theme configuration... still not working !!

Comment: 99.9999% of the time, this is the cause. The browser weirdness mentioned in the other case is probably rare unless you're using Chrome or have bolloxed up your server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I got this in my PHP log. So for me the solution was to increase the amoutn of input variables to 10000 via .htaccess file

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini
```